# I have used konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend for setting up my docker registry. Can I append logo to docker-registry-frontend?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have used konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend for setting up my docker registry. Can I append logo to docker-registry-frontend?
if so plz let me know how to do it.

I have used the following docker-compose.yml to built a private docker registry

```
---
version: '3'

services:
    docker-registry:
        container_name: docker-registry
        image: registry:2
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./volume:/var/lib/registry
    docker-registry-ui:
        container_name: docker-registry-ui
        image: konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST: docker-registry
            ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT: 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login to container -> docker-registry-frontend:v2
and search for the files which are present normally it will be present in /var/www/html and there makes changes in index.html and restart apache